# python reverse string ::-1 slice function equivalent

Tags: python, string, slice

I see how `"String"[::-1]` works to return `"gnirtS"`

But isn't this supposed to be compatible with the slice function?

`"String"[slice(-1, 0, -1)]` ?

This returns `"gnirt"`

Comment: `slice(-1, 0, -1)` is not equivalent to `[::-1]`. `slice(None, None, -1)` is.

Comment: Remember that the end of a slice is exclusive, so `slice(-1, 0, -1)` stops at index `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 2):

`slice(-1, 0, -1)` is not equivalent to `[::-1]`. `slice(None, None, -1)` is.

```
class SliceNotationTranslator:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(item)

s = SliceNotationTranslator()
s[::-1]
```

Outputs

```
slice(None, None, -1)
```